# How to extract with XPath a text containting < not encoded as &lt;

Tags: html, xpath, scrapy, html-entities

I want to extract some text from an html page using Scrapy.

One of the elements contains a `<` character which is not encoded as `&lt;` (the page is not valid html).

For example

```
<div>
  years < 7
</div>
```

With XPath (in Chrome or in Scapy code) using `'//div/text()'` I can only extract `'years'`

Is there a way to get the full text ie `'years < 7'`?

Comment: What happens if you use `//div[not(*)]` and get the `.textContent` of the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use other module instead of basic Select
for example I use my own

```
from lxml import etree
from lxml.html.clean import clean_html

import html5lib
from lxml.etree import XMLSyntaxError, XPathEvalErro

def parse_user(self, response):        
    m = smarte_html_parser.dive_html_root_level(html=response.body)
```

from
    
    
        Some Title
    
    
        
            years < 7

I got years < 7

Answer (score 1):

XPath operates on the DOM level, not on how things are encoded.  XPath does not see whether entities were used for certain things or not.  This is the DOM parsers business.  So, if the DOM parser dropped `< 7` because it could not make sense of it, then XPath won't see that part at all.

To get reliable results, fix the HTML by other means before applying XPath.